# Use REPLACE with a concatenated string in DB2

Tags: sql, replace, db2, concatenation

```
StringA
StringB
StringC
StringD
```

I am concatenating the above 4 strings as given below

```
StringA||' '||StringB||' '||StringC||' '||StringD
```

I wish to use a REPLACE on the above concatenated string so that it replaces double spaces by single space. I have something like this

```
REPLACE((StringA||' '||StringB||' '||StringC||' '||StringD), '  ',' ')
```

However, the above logic does not provide me results.

But if I just apply it for StringA and StringB, it works fine. How can we make it work for the complete string?

Comment: Which version of DB2?  What _is_ it providing you with?  Are you sure you have actual _spaces_?  There are a multitude of different whitespace characters.  If you don't need this db-side, perhaps do the replacing in the application layer - many languages have better support/libraries for this.  The answer you've accepted doesn't appear to be valid for your stated db - does it actually work?

Comment: Your SQL looks correct.  Just you do not have double spaces at the end:  ,'  ',' ' (seems to be SO reformatting)

Answer (score 0):

Try regexp:

```
   regexp_replace(String1||''||String2||.....||Stringn, '[ ]+', ' ' )
```

Comment: `regexp_replace` appears to be an **Oracle** function, yet the question is tagged DB2....  Could I get documentation on this, please?  To my knowledge, DB2 _still_ doesn't have native regex.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree that DB2 does not hqve regexp_replqce, but it has regex when using xQuery: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrregexp.html

Comment: @AngocA - Agreed - I guess I wasn't considering that 'native' because I though xQuery wasn't on by default.  Or something.  Well, that and because I've never used it, so I keep forgetting about it...  #sigh#....

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is probably:

```
REPLACE(( TRIM(StringA)||' '||TRIM(StringB)||' '||TRIM(StringC)||' '||TRIM(StringD)), '  ',' ')
```

That should handle all cases where trailing spaces give substrings of multiple spaces in the result. After that, you'll only be concerned if the original four strings contain substrings of three or more spaces to begin with. If that's the case, we probably need to know more about the definitions of all four string columns.

Comment: I've just formatted the code blocks in the question and it has revealed that the REPLACE's second argument was actually `'  '` (two spaces), just FYI.

Comment: @AndriyM I should've noticed that my suggested modification had only a single space. I didn't verify because I copied from the TS and merely added the TRIM()s to it. The copy/paste somehow succeeded where the original problem didn't! (I edited my suggestion to add a second space.)